# Why don't comment upvotes work? thinkster.io, angularjs tutorial, mean, incrementUpvote()

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm following the thinkster angular js tutorial here:

https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/mean-stack-tutorial/

and clicking on the upvotes icon next to a comment fails to increment the upvote count.

In a ui-router template(included inline in index.html), an ng-click calls addUpvote()--but addUpvote() is defined by a controller specified in another state.  So the only way the template can call addUpvote() is if the template's associated state/controller somehow inherits from the other state/controller.  And in fact, according to the ui-router docs here:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

the way the states are defined in my app.js,

app.js:

```
app.config([
'$stateProvider', 
'$urlRouterProvider', 
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', { 
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl' }
    )
    .state('posts', {  
      url: '/posts/{id}',
      templateUrl: '/posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl' }
    );

}]);
```

...the second state inherits from the first state **Edit:** A more careful reading of the docs makes me believe that isn't actually true; I think that in order for the `posts` state to inherit from the `home` state, I would have to change the name of the `posts` state to `home.posts`.  However, when I try that, it breaks something else: the comments link next to a post no longer works.  In any case, I don't think writing:

```
$stateProvider
  .state(...)
  .state(...);
```

creates any inheritance between the two states.

Here is the first state's controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts', function($scope, posts) {
  $scope.posts = posts.posts;
  /*
  [
    {title: "post1", upvotes: 3, link: ''},
    {title: "post2", upvotes: 5, link: ''},
    {title: "post3", upvotes: 1, link: ''}
  ];
*/
  $scope.addPost = function() {
    var title = $scope.title;

    if (title && (title.trim().length > 0) ) {
      $scope.posts.push({
        title: title, 
        upvotes: 0, 
        link: $scope.link,
        comments: [
          {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
          {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea, but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
        ]
      });
    }

    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.link = '';
  }

  //*****HERE IS THE FUNCTION THAT IS NOT BEING CALLED*****
  $scope.addUpvote = function(post) {
    console.log("in addUpvote");
    ++post.upvotes;
  }

}]);
```

As far as I can determine, my template should be able to call addUpvote(). However, the console.log() line doesn't output anything when I click on the upvote icon next to a comment, so obviously addUpvote() is not being called.

Here is a portion of index.html:

```
<body ng-app="flapperNews">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>
....
....
....
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h3>
      <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
        {{post.title}}
      </a>
      <span ng-hide="post.link">
        {{post.title}}
      </span>
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
          ng-click="addUpvote(comment)"></span>

    {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}

    <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
      {{comment.body}}
    </span>
  </div>
</script>
</body>
```

Towards the bottom of that template, ng-click calls addUpvote().  Why isn't addUpvote() being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation was a little further down in the docs:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#scope-inheritance-by-view-hierarchy-only

> **Scope Inheritance by View Hierarchy Only**
>
> Keep in mind that scope properties only inherit down the state chain
>   if the views of your states are nested. **Inheritance of scope
>   properties has nothing to do with the nesting of your states** and
>   everything to do with the nesting of your views (templates).
>
> It is entirely possible that you have nested states whose templates
>   populate ui-views at various non-nested locations within your site. **In
>   this scenario you cannot expect to access the scope variables of
>   parent state views within the views of children states.**

And:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states

> **What Do Child States Inherit From Parent States?**
>
> Child states DO inherit the following from parent states:
>
> Resolved dependencies via resolve
>   Custom data properties
>   Nothing else is inherited (no controllers, templates, url, etc).
>   ...
>   ...
>   Child states will inherit data properties from parent state(s), which
>   they can overwrite.

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
      data:{
         customData1:  "Hello",
         customData2:  "World!"
      }
   })
   .state('parent.child', {
      data:{
         // customData1 inherited from 'parent'
         // but we'll overwrite customData2
         customData2:  "UI-Router!"
      }
   });
```

So to make the comment upvotes work, I did this:

```
app.controller('PostsCtrl', [
'$scope', 
'$stateParams', 
'posts',
function($scope, $stateParams, posts) {
  $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];

  $scope.addUpvote = function(comment) {
    console.log('comment upvote');
    ++comment.upvotes;
  }

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and when I ran the url in cURL, it returned  req.comment.upvote is not a function at the top of the error stack.

C:\Users\ddavis>curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/posts/57b380f850eaca0c1233a3b7/comments/57b42f4b305a94e40c75970d/upvote
req.comment.upvote is not a function
...

In my case, when I defined an upvote function in the comments.js model like below it worked:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        body: String,
        author: String,
        upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
        posts: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}]    
         
});

CommentSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
  this.upvotes += 1;
  this.save(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

C:\Users\ddavis>curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/posts/57b380f850eaca0c1233a3b7/comments/57b42f4b305a94e40c75970d/upvote
{"_id":"57b42f4b305a94e40c75970d","body":"another comment","author":"user","__v":0,"posts":[],"upvotes":3}